What did Gell‐Mann dislike about Feynman’s book?
An anecdote attributed to Al Seckel relates:

There was another lunch conversation that involved Gell-Mann that took place right after the publication of Surely You’re Joking.  Gell-Mann, who I was quite friendly with too, confided to me that he was very upset with Feynman’s written account of their joint discovery of the theory of beta decay. He felt that Feynman had not reported the account accurately and was giving himself undue credit. At lunch the mood was jovial, and I took the occasion to pass along Gell-Mann’s feelings about the controversial passage. Feynman’s smile immediately disappeared. He looked rather sad and hurt. … Feynman did indeed change the passage to suit Gell-Mann’s wishes.

What specifically did Gell‐Mann dislike about the description of the discovery of beta decay in the first edition of Surely You’re Joking, Mr. Feynman? What did Feynman and Ralph Leighton, the book’s author, change in this portion of the book in later editions?

It is about description of Feynman's discovery of the vector (V) minus axial (A) theory of weak interaction. Gell-Mann disliked that the book said that Feynman was the only one to came up with it. Note that the book was written by Ralph Leighton, Feynman just gave his support to write the book from his recordings.
I checked the early British edition of the book published by COUNTERPOINT Unwin Paperbacks (1986), it writes in page 250:

Finally they get all this stuff into me, Situation is so mixed up that even some of the things they've established for years are being questioned—such as the beta decay of the neutron is S and T. Murray says it might even be V and A, it’s so messed up.”
I jump up from the stool and say, "Then I understand EVVVVVERYTHING!"
They thought I was joking. But the thing that I had trouble with the Rochester meeting–the neutron and proton disintegration: everything fit but that, and if it was V and A instead of S and T, that would fit too, Therefore I had the whole theory!
That night I calculated all kinds of things with this theory. The first thing I calculated was the rate of disintegration of the mu and the neutron. They should be connected together, if this theory was right, by a certain relationship, and it was right to 9 percent. That's pretty close, 9 percent. It should have been more perfect than that, but it was close enough.
I went on and checked some other things, which fit, and new things fit, and I was very excited. It was the first time, and the only time, in my career that I knew a law of nature that that nobody else knew.

Emphasis mine. But in later versions, the last paragraph reads

I went on and checked some other things, which fit, and new things fit, new things fit, and I was very excited. It was the first time, and the only time, in my career that I knew a law of nature that nobody else knew. (Of course it wasn't true, but finding out later that at least Murray Gell-­Mann and also Sudarshan and Marshak had worked out the same theory didn't spoil my fun.)

This is confirmed by this news article:

Flipping through the pages, Gell-Mann found Feynman's account of the theory of the weak nuclear force, the one they had reluctantly collaborated on. "I was very excited," Feynman said. "It was the first time, and the only time, in my career that I knew a law of nature that nobody else knew." Gell-Mann, enraged, said he would sue. In a later edition Feynman conceded that Gell-Mann and two other physicists had also thought of the idea. But the disclaimer didn't heal the wound.

From G. Johnson, "The Jaguar and the Fox", The Atlantic (2000).
